# Get the elements of div within the div when mouseover

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I'd like to get only the elements of the hovered DOM, but when I started hovering it also trigger the parents dom like this;

```
<div class="testclass">
    <div class="divEditmsg">Click to Edit</div>
    <div class="testclass">
        <div class="divEditmsg">Click to Edit</div>
        <div class="testclass">
            <div class="divEditmsg">Click to Edit</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).append('<div class="divEditmsg">Click to Edit</div>');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('.divEditmsg').remove();
    }
}, ".testclass");
```

Comment: Call `e.stopPropagation()` in your mouseenter. http://jsfiddle.net/j03t1z3u/

Comment: Thanks @JackPattishallJr. It work. But when I hovered the parent from child append doesn't work.

Comment: Hey @JestherBangculetaBas, what's the use case? You have nested elements, each of which can trigger an `append`?

Answer (score 0):

The comment is correct but incomplete.

Why are you binding this event to the `$(document)` object?  Why not bind directly to the div that you want to effect.  It is not exactly clear what you are trying to do here, but you want to bind to the child most element you can.  Then if it is messing with other event handlers, use `event.stopPropagation` to stop event bubbling.

Your main issue though, I believe, in this case, is what selectors  you have listening for the mouse events.

Comment: I'm speculating here - but my guess is event delegation (akin to the deprecated $.live() binding). A common parent element, or even document.body would be more clear, though.

Comment: The `event.stopPropagation` works well but when I hovered the parent from child, the append doesn't work anymore.

I used the `$(document)` because the `testclass divs` can be add dynamically.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to happens.  Briefly, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry @user1167442, in here [http://jsfiddle.net/j03t1z3u/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/j03t1z3u/2/) If you do hover from a to b the `divEditmsg` shows up correctly but if you hovered from c to a.
 @JackPattishallJr

Comment: Ah, got you. That's how the browser works. (you've technically "entered" the DIV, when hovering over the child element). It sounds like what you want is `mousemove`. Here's an updated (but terribly, inefficient) fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j03t1z3u/3/

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want whatever element you enter to append and remove the text on mouseover and mouseout?